# Linking C++ library to a view based application. [XCODE]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to link C++ based library file to an view based xcode project.
I am building a application for iPhone simulator.

So question is, is it possible to link C++ library to a objective-c project?
If yes then do I need to have an interface in between Objective-C code and the Library?
 or can I use lib C++ functions/classes directly in the Objective-C class/methods.

Can some one please point to some good tutorials/examples to how to load a C++ based lib   and use it in View based application in XCODE.

I have gone through this link:
http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/xcode-static-libraries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be much you need to do.  Have you renamed all files that uses the library to `.mm`?  After that, everything should work the same.  You can put C++ code on 1 line, then put Objective-C code the other line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have renamed all the files to .mm, but i don't know how i can include lib file in XCODE. and include while build. i know i need to have some interface in-between C++ and Obj-C files to call functions from C++ of Obj-C. and I can call C++  functions from Objective-C code when file is .mm, but i don't know where to add .h file related to lib and the .a lib file in my project.

Comment: Add it wherever you need it..?  How would you add the library to a C++ project?  Do the same thing in Objective-C++.